# MVC Count and Sum Multiple Recorset Single View

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to return the count of one recordset and the sum of another recordset in one function to display within a view?

I also need the most efficient method, typically a query as below returns a full Recorset using all fields specified for the table/class Contents:

```
var usersModel = from m in db.AspNetUsers where != m.UserName == "Bob" select m;

return View(contentModel);
```

But I just need the recordset count, no other fields as that's not an efficent use of SQL.

The next is to return the sum of another table/class again no other fields just the field Amount.

Can this be done within one function and display both values in a single view?

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view model to hold your results. Something like this...

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int UserCount { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Then populate the viewmodel using 2 queries. Something like this...

```
var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
viewModel.UserCount = (from m in db.AspNetUsers where m.UserName == "Bob").Count();
viewModel.TotalAmount = db.Orders.Where(o => o.CustomerName == "Bob").Sum(o => o.Amount);

return View(viewModel);
```

View...

```
@model MyProject.MyViewModel

<div>count = @Model.UserCount</div>
<div>total = @Model.TotalAmount<div>
```

Comment: Two queries, this is what I can't get my head around, using T-SQL and Classic ASP it could be achieved with one query and one Response.Write, finding MVC a little frustrating and bloated.

Comment: EF can handle sprocs including ones that return 2 resultsets (at least EF using EDMX does). But usually this is a micro-optimization with little benefit. Write the 2 EF queries, enjoy the simplicity that an ORM provides, and optimize with TSQL or raw SQL when you find a performance issue. In my experience this is a small percentage of queries and not worth sweating over.

Comment: Can I create a class called Statistics in WebApplication1.Models with the code for MyViewModel then in the HomeController located in WebAppliaction1.Controllers add the query code to a [ChildActionOnly] public ActionResult Statistics(), finally add the count and total to the View Statistics?

Comment: I've got the first part working `statsModel.UserCount = (from m in db.AspNetUsers where m.UserName != "Bob" select new { m.UserName }).Count();` unfortunately the sum does not work, I just need the sum of the Amount field, no where clause required.

Comment: Please, what is wrong with `statsModel.TotalAmount = (from o in db.Orders select o.Amount).Sum();`

Answer (score 0):

The biggest headache was the sum as the example provided a decimal value yet my field was actually a Nullable so no matter what linq syntax I was using Visual Studio 2013 would never verify it.

I have provide a full solution below to my initial problem:

WebApplication1/Models/StatisticsModels.cs

```
public class StatisticsModels
{
    public int UserCount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

WebApplication1/Controllers/HomeController.cs

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Statistics()
{
    var statsModel = new StatisticsModels();
    statsModel.UserCount = (from m in db.AspNetUsers where m.UserName != "bob" select new { m.UserName }).Count();
    statsModel.TotalAmount = db.Orders.Sum(o => o.Amount);
        return View(statsModel);
    }
```

WebApplication1/Views/Home/Statistics.cshtml

```
@{ Layout = null; }

@model WebApplication1.Models.StatisticsModels

<div>Count = @Model.UserCount</div>
<div>Sum = @Model.TotalAmount</div>
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Statistics", "Home"); }
```

I hope this provides useful to others :-)